# Верный подсчет результата при нажатии на чекбокс

Tags: java, android

Приложения теста. Когда выбираешь верный ответ, приложение прибавляет к результату одно очко.

Проблема в том, что если снять галочку и поставить галочку еще раз, система прибавит уже 2 очка. Сколько нажимаешь на ответ, столько он и прибавляет, а должен всегда делать +1.

Вот код:

```
//Question 2 radio button
public void questionOneRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    RadioButton questionTwoAnswer = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.question_one_answer_a);
    boolean questionTwoAnswerA = questionTwoAnswer.isChecked();
    RadioGroup  radioGroup = (RadioGroup )findViewById(R.id.second_question);
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.question_one_answer_a:
            if (questionTwoAnswerA) {
                MyScore += 1;
            }
        case R.id.question_one_answer_b:
            if (checked) {
                MyScore += 0;
            }

        case R.id.question_one_answer_c:
            if (checked) {
                MyScore += 0;
            }
    }
}

//Question 3 checkboxes IT IS MULTIPLE. TWO RIGHT ANSWERS!!
public void questionTwoChecked(View view) {
    CheckBox questionTwoAnswerA = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_two_answer_a);
    boolean questionTwoAnswerAChecked = questionTwoAnswerA.isChecked();
    CheckBox questionTwoAnswerB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_two_answer_b);
    boolean questionTwoAnswerBChecked = questionTwoAnswerB.isChecked();
    CheckBox questionTwoAnswerC = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.question_two_answer_c);
    boolean questionTwoAnswerCChecked = questionTwoAnswerC.isChecked();
    if (questionTwoAnswerAChecked) {
        MyScore += 0;
    }
    if (questionTwoAnswerBChecked && questionTwoAnswerCChecked) {
        MyScore += 2;
    }
    if (questionTwoAnswerCChecked || questionTwoAnswerBChecked) {
        MyScore += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Поместите код непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: только не весь код, а часть, непосредственно отвечающюю за проблему в вопросе. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ.

Comment: `switch-case` без `break` порой приводят к самым неожиданным результатам.